# Does the Essentials Berserker benefit from non-essentials Rages in powers?

Tags: dnd-4e

If you have an Essentials Berserker and you choose a non-Essentials barbarian power with a Rage effect, do you still gain the benefits from the non-Essentials Rage listed in the power?

For instance if I have the "Thunder Hooves Rage" can I still move through enemies and gain the extra damage when attacking the enemies I move through?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you gain all benefits.**

The effect is part of the power, and not of the original barbarian class. You would gain the benefits even if you got the power with the Adept Power feat on a Ranger for example.